# REST Server with my module service returns 404

Tags: services

I have set up my drupal REST using `REST Server` and `services`. Also I have created my own module which implements `hook_services_resources()`.

I have configured REST with to use my resource and node.

This works:
http://local/rest/node/1

This does not work (returns 404):
http://local/rest/hotel_search

Here is my module:

```
function MY_MODULE_services_resources() {
    return array(
        'hotel_search' => array(
            'retrieve' => array(
                'help' => 'Search for Hotels',
                'callback' => 'MY_MODULE_hotel_search',
                'access callback' => 'MY_MODULE_access_callback',
                'args' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'name',
                        'description' => 'hotel name',
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'source' => 'param',
                        'optional' => false,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

function MY_MODULE_access_callback() {
    return true;
}


function MY_MODULE_hotel_search() {
    $json = array(
        'name' => 'response',
        'status' => 'ok'
    );
    return json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the names of the Access callbacks don't match?

Comment: They are the same. I updated the code.

Comment: Try using the `actions` array when declaring your resource, then use a POST to use it: http://www.drupalgap.org/node/187 - I believe the CRUD routing only works on the entity level, and not on the custom service resource level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Services module, the "CRUD" resources are typically mapped only to entities, and routed to each based on the HTTP method:

```
GET -> Retrieve
POST -> Created
PUT -> Update
DELETE -> Delete
```

When building a custom service resource, you need to use the `actions` array when building your resource. In your example, your resources array would become:

```
return array(
  'my_module_resources' => array(
    'actions' => array(
        'hotel_search' => array(
            'help' => 'Search for Hotels',
            'callback' => 'MY_MODULE_hotel_search',
            'access callback' => 'MY_MODULE_access_callback',
            'args' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'description' => 'hotel name',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'source' => 'param',
                    'optional' => false,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your `callback` can just return an array or object, it doesn't need to encode the result, because Services will automatically do that based on the extension on the URL, e.g. `.json`.

You'd then make a call to it with a POST to:

```
?q=rest/my_module_resources/hotel_search.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that, with the Services module, `json_encode` happens outside of the callback function you write.

Try to just return `$json` without encoding it, and see if that helps. If I'm correct, it will return JSON anyway.

Comment: Still got 404. Also response headers contain: `Status Code: 404 Not found: Could not find the controller.`

Comment: At this point, you should be able to go into `/admin/structure/services/list` and see `hotel_search` and then `retrieve` under that. Is the Service enabled?

Comment: It's enabled there.